# Development Server Blocked Only from Home

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, firewall

Recently I've been having an issue with my CentOS 6 test server running Apache and Webmin running on port 10000 where when I try accessing any part of the server - SSH/FTP and even my domains (I have two - both keep getting timeout errors) when I try accessing from any computer on my home network.

However when I access via tethering or via my office networks everything loads fine.

While the firewall is the first issue at mind, my router never was set to block any special ports, and even after adding port 10000 as a specific exception I'm having no luck.

Also, I doubt this is an IP blacklisting issue because I have websites on other servers using CloudFlare for security and I haven't gotten any warnings.

Any assistance is greatly apprecaiated.

UPDATE: Just some extra details about the issue:  My ISP to my knowledge only blocks off ports 25 and 80 for residential users to prevent them from running web servers - however this issue has only come up a day or two ago, before that I was using the server successfully for months.

Also the server is not physically located in any of my workspaces - it's a VPS housed in a datacenter

UPDATE TWO:  I've narrowed this issue down to my home router because when I do a direct wire to the modem I do not have the error (which are server timeouts). Additionally I was able to access my site wirelessly shortly via Comodo TrustConnect (which is a VPN) but after an hour or so of working the timeout came back and the software did not help on my other systems.

Setting my notebooks to the DMZ also provided temporary relief but as with the VPN it got choked up after an hour or so of working.

Currently my router is a Linksys/Cisco E200 Wireless N Router and it has been working fine for awhile now so I'm not sure what caused this issue. Any insights are greatly appreciated as this issue has even boggled a few of my colleges. I'm thinking of buying a new router, but as this is specific to just my one website I'm a bit iffy as it seems extreme.

Comment: Is that server on the same network as the system you're trying to access it from?

Comment: Does your home ISP filter anything port-wise?

Comment: Have you tried running `nmap` against your server from home/work and comparing the results?

Answer (score 1):

I would start by running `tcpdump` or `wireshark` (command line version of WireShark is `tshark`).  These tools let you see the actual network packets on your server.  Using that, you can see with certainty whether the packets from your other machine are making it to your server.  If you see them, it's a problem with the server.  If you don't see the traffic attempts from your other computer, the problem lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Has the server itself blocked your home IP address? Have you checked its logs?

Assuming your home Internet connection has a dynamic IP address you could try rebooting the modem, which in most cases will also get you a new IP address, after which you could retry the connection.